# Dynamically adjust stored procedure with one variable holding multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that takes an input parameter as follows:

```
@Name NVARCHAR(50) = 'George W Bush'
```

How can I adjust my where clause dynamically:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(FIELD, 'George')
  AND CONTAINS(FIELD, 'W')
  AND CONTAINS(FIELD, 'Bush')
```

Or for example:

```
@Name NVARCHAR(50) = 'Harry Potter'

SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(FIELD, 'Harry')
  AND CONTAINS(FIELD, 'Potter')
```

I have found many solutions here that come so close to doing what I need, but I specifically need for the field to contain each substring of the input parameter.

Comment: The substrings are always space-delimited?

Comment: Yes they will always be space-delimited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CONTAINS` can work with multiple words with `AND` or `OR` conditions like this:

```
 WHERE CONTAINS (FIELD, 'George AND W AND Bush')
```

So what you can do is change your variable to(given they will always be space-delimited):

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Name = REPLACE('George W Bush', ' ', ' AND ')

SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(FIELD, @Name)
```

Comment: I ended up having the following issue after I created a full-text index for my table:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719099/null-or-empty-full-text-predicate-when-executing-a-store-procedure-from-a-boun

However, this solution worked the best for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to split your names, regardless if it is FirstName LastName, or FirstName MiddleName LastName, into parameters which you can use. Of course if you expect more than 2 spaces (three names) this won't work

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = 'George W Bush' 
DECLARE @Spaces int = (SELECT LEN(@Name)-LEN(REPLACE(@Name, ' ', '')))

DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50) = null
DECLARE @MiddleName varchar(50) = null
DECLARE @LastName varchar(50) = null

IF @Spaces = 2 
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstName = LEFT(@Name,CHARINDEX(' ',@Name))
        SET @MiddleName = SUBSTRING(@Name,CHARINDEX(' ',@Name) + 1,1)
        SET @LastName = RIGHT(@Name,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Name)))
    END
ELSE IF @Spaces = 1 
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstName = LEFT(@Name,CHARINDEX(' ',@Name))
        SET @LastName = RIGHT(@Name,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Name)))
    END


SELECT @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINS` will work if your table is full-text indexed, but if it isn't, consider this:

```
-- Here's my test data
declare @t table
(
   text nvarchar(max)
)

insert @t values('I''m just wild about Harry')
              , ('Sally Potter is important in British theater')
              , ('I love the "Harry Potter" books')


-- Here are our keywords:
declare @Name varchar(max) = 'Harry Potter'

-- To make this work, we need to convert the substrings into tabular form.  
-- so here's how we'll do that. 

declare @NameXml xml 

set @NameXml = convert(xml, '<substrings><substring>' + 
               replace(@Name, ' ', '</substring><substring>') +
               '</substring></substrings>')

-- That gives us an XML variable with each substring as a separate 
-- element.
;
with mockTable as 
(
    select  Keyword = N.a.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    from    @NameXml.nodes('/substrings/substring') as N(a)
)
-- Now that we have a "mock table", we can use the ALL operator to 
-- confirm that each string in our mock table is found in the
-- records we return.
select  *
from    @t
where   1 = ALL (
    select  case 
            when [text] like '%' + Keyword + '%'
            then 1
            else 0
            end
    from mockTable
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ann L. said, CONTAINS and FREETEXT only work when you've already created the FULLTEXT INDEX on the underlying table.
As per you need this string-parsing operation, why not create a user-defined function to handle that, and use it within your Sproc. BTW, I really dont want to use wild cards. :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[parsing]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(2000),
    @Delimiter NVARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS @Rtn TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Seg NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Rtn (Seg)
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)-1)))
        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)+LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@String))
    END
    INSERT INTO @Rtn (Seg)
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@String))
END
```