# Can CONTAINS Handle Table Columns that have NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do some query performance and I've been looking into applying a FULLTEXT INDEX as compared to using LIKE.

I have a database w/person information, i.e. FirstName, LastName, etc. where some of those columns are null.

When I try to use CONTAINS object, I'm getting this error message;

```
Null or empty full-text predicate
```

I've put in code to ensure the passed in @FirstName field is not null, and if a null was passed in then I've set it to ' "" ' like I've read elsewhere. I still get the error message. I'm starting to wonder if it's a problem because the index has columns that are null.

Does anyone know if that is the case, I've looked everywhere and I cannot find any information on this.

Here is the query. The @FirstNameLocal and @LastNameLocal are passed into this stored procedure. In this example, FirstName and/or LastName field data in the PersonTable could be null. I'm using SQL Server 2012 w/SP1. "Try to use" means when I try to run the query in SQL Management Studio.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, PersonId
FROM PersonTable
Where IsDeleted = 0
AND CONTAINS(FirstName, @FirstNameLocal)
AND CONTAINS(LastName, @LastNameLocal)
```

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189765/7645-null-or-empty-full-text-predicate

Comment: Show us your current query

Comment: Also please: What does "try to use" mean? Compile? Run? Give us your SQL Server version and table definitions. And if applicable example input & output and desired output. Read about MVCEs.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way? I'm not seeing upvotes or acceptance of my answer... Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether your variable IS NULL or equals an empty string first. I think though that this will partially negate the benefit of full-text indexes and you should consider handling this differently (for instance with dynamic SQL).

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, PersonId
FROM PersonTable
Where IsDeleted = 0
AND (ISNULL(@FirstNameLocal,'')='' OR CONTAINS(FirstName, @FirstNameLocal))
AND (ISNULL(@LastNameLocal,'')='' OR CONTAINS(LastName, @LastNameLocal));
```

If you would do this with dynamic SQL it would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @stmt=
    N'SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, PersonId ' +
    N'FROM PersonTable ' +
    N'Where IsDeleted = 0' +
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@FirstNameLocal,'')='' 
        THEN N''
        ELSE N' AND CONTAINS(FirstName, @FirstNameLocal)'
    END +
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@LastNameLocal,'')='' 
        THEN N''
        ELSE N' AND CONTAINS(LastName, @LastNameLocal)'
    END + ';'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt,
    N'@FirstNameLocal VARCHAR(256),@LastNameLocal VARCHAR(256)',
    @FirstNameLocal,
    @LastNameLocal;
```

The downside is that the statement is compiled again each time this script is run, but this will be small compared to the benefit of full-text indexes that can be used in this statement.

Always compare the [Actual Execution Plans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms189562.aspx) to choose which version is best.

Comment: could you show an example of what you mean handle it with dynamic sql?

Comment: @RobStewart Example added